# Referencing enumeration items by number and name

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumitem

I'm currently using `enumitem` for automatically numbering several requirements in my thesis. However, as each requirement has not only a number but also a short title, when referencing to it using `\ref` (or `\cref`, if that makes things easier), I'd like the output to include both.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand*{\req}[1]{\item \emph{#1}\quad}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=R \arabic*,widest*=20,leftmargin=*,series=reqs]
\req{First One} First requirement.
\req{Other One} \label{req:other_one} Some other requirement.
\end{enumerate}

Some text....

\begin{enumerate}[resume*=reqs]
\req{Yet Another Requirement} Text.
\end{enumerate}

As mentioned in \ref{req:other_one}, ...

\end{document}
```

In the last line, it currently just says "As mentioned in R 2". What I'd like to achieve is "As mentioned in R 2 (Other One)".

Comment: Do you *always* want such references to be like "R 2 (Other One)"?

Comment: @egreg: As a bonus, it would be great if I could choose for each reference (eg. by using some other command). However, if they always show up with the title, this is fine with me too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all your references are of the form “R 2 (Other One)” you can do by adding the required text to `\@currentlabel`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\req}[1]{%
  \item
  \appto\@currentlabel{ (#1)}%
  \emph{#1}\quad}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=R~\arabic*,widest*=20,leftmargin=*,series=reqs]
\req{First One} First requirement.
\req{Other One} \label{req:other_one} Some other requirement.
\end{enumerate}

Some text....

\begin{enumerate}[resume*=reqs]
\req{Yet Another Requirement} Text.
\end{enumerate}

As mentioned in \ref{req:other_one}, ...

\end{document}
```

Note the tie between `R` and the number.

If you want to choose between the two forms “R 2 (Other One)” and “R 2”, then either you define two labels, which is clumsy, or use a different command for referencing the requirements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\req}[1]{%
  \item
  \appto\@currentlabel{\req@print{#1}}%
  \emph{#1}\quad}
\newif\if@reqprint
\newrobustcmd{\reqref}{%
  \@ifstar{\@reqprintfalse\ref}{\@reqprinttrue\ref}%
}
\newrobustcmd{\req@print}[1]{\if@reqprint\ (#1)\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=R~\arabic*,widest*=20,leftmargin=*,series=reqs]
\req{First One} \label{req:first_one} First requirement.
\req{Other One} \label{req:other_one} Some other requirement.
\end{enumerate}

Some text....

\begin{enumerate}[resume*=reqs]
\req{Yet Another Requirement} Text.
\end{enumerate}

As mentioned in \reqref{req:other_one}, and in \reqref*{req:first_one}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I had in mind, thanks a lot!