# Subitem in enumerate written as <item#>.<subitem#> instead of indentation

Tags: indentation, enumerate

I want to define different requirements in my thesis, some of which can be divided into smaller requirements. Building on the answer to my previous question [Referencing enumeration items by number and name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120756/referencing-enumeration-items-by-number-and-name), I came up with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\req}[1]{%
  \item %
  \let\originall@bel\@currentlabel%
  \appto\@currentlabel{ (#1)}%
  \emph{#1}\quad}
\newenvironment{subreqs}{\begin{enumerate}[label=\originall@bel.\arabic*,widest=9,leftmargin=0pt]}{\end{enumerate}}
\makeatother

\begin{enumerate}[label=R~\arabic*,widest*=20,leftmargin=*,series=reqs]
\req{First Important Thing} \label{req1} \lipsum[4]
\begin{subreqs}
\req{Important Subitem} \label{req2} \lipsum[2]
\end{subreqs}
\end{enumerate}

\ref{req1} and \ref{req2} are important.

\end{document}
```

This partly works as expected, the only problem is that the second requirement is indented with regard to the first one. This is of course expected since I use a second level of `enumerate`, but I'd still like to avoid it since the grouping is visible from the number itself.

[image]

**Edit:** I just realized that `leftmargin` (which I suspected to do something different) controls exactly what I want. However, using `leftmargin=0pt` instead of `leftmargin=*` in the definition of `subreqs`, as Thruston suggests does not really help, as it makes `R 1.1` protrude out of the text frame (see the updated code/screenshot above).

Comment: Try changing your `subreqs` environment to define `leftmargin=0pt`. Does this do what you want?

Comment: @Thruston: thanks for pointing this out, I thought that `leftmargin` only controlled the indentation of the wrapped lines following the item. However, setting it to `0pt` does not really solve the problem either (see the updated question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set `leftmargin=0pt` for the inner list. I suggest defining your own environment also for the outer list. There is no need for `\originall@bel`, but an `\ignorespaces` is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newlist{reqs}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{subreqs}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[reqs]{label=R~\arabic*,widest*=100,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[subreqs]{label=\thereqsi.\arabic*,leftmargin=0pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\req}[1]{%
  \item 
  \appto\@currentlabel{ (#1)}%
  \emph{#1}\quad\ignorespaces}% <--- note \ignorespaces
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]
\begin{reqs}
\req{First Important Thing} \label{req1} \lipsum[4]
\begin{subreqs}
\req{Important Subitem} \label{req2} \lipsum[2]
\end{subreqs}
\end{reqs}
\lipsum[3]

\ref{req1} and \ref{req2} are important.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want left alignment of the labels, you can pass the label width of the outer environment to the inner one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newlist{reqs}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{subreqs}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[reqs]{
  label=R~\arabic*,
  widest*=100,
  leftmargin=*,
  align=left,
  before=\edef\outerlabelwidth{\the\labelwidth}
}
\setlist[subreqs]{
  label=\thereqsi.\arabic*,
  leftmargin=0pt,
  labelindent=0pt,
  labelwidth=\outerlabelwidth,
  align=left,
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\req}[1]{%
  \item %
  \appto\@currentlabel{ (#1)}%
  \emph{#1}\quad\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]
\begin{reqs}
\req{First Important Thing} \label{req1} \lipsum[4]
\begin{subreqs}
\req{Important Subitem} \label{req2} \lipsum[2]
\end{subreqs}
\end{reqs}
\lipsum[3]

\ref{req1} and \ref{req2} are important.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is nearly where I wanted it... I realize I'm nit-picking now, but is there any way to left-align the labels `R 1` and `R 1.1`? I just played around with `align=left`, which seems to work for the first level of indentation, but moves the label of `R 1.1` to the *right* if I add it in `\setlist[subreqs]{...}`.

Comment: @rainer Left alignment added